# How to Start with tablet development

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, tablet

I have been task with a tablet application project; all my experience is with Windows Apps (VFP and C# .Net WebForms). The app will initially be Android based but must have the architecture to port to iPad, Windows Tablet without too much re-write.

The application must work "offline" so I need to use local data and not be web based so as I understand it HTML5 is out.

I am leaning towards C# .Net and using Mono, but have struggled to find resources on keeping the UI size independent and how to create and access a database (SQLite?).

After some real newbie ideas and links please or maybe a simple sample app to show cross platform limitations and flexibility.

Gary.

Answer (score 1):

> or maybe a simple sample app

Here's a [full sample](http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/02/24/mwc_2012/) of an application that was designed to work on Android, iOS (both iPhone and iPad) and Windows Phone.

Everything is there, including SQLite support, to show you how to maximize code reuse across the three platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). I haven't used it myself but I've heard good things about it. And it looks like you can access native functionality across different devices so you'll be able to use local storage.

Comment: I did look at PhoneGap, but it's HTML5 and I could not work out if it did or did not need a web connection at runtime.

Comment: @Gary2Seven - The PhoneGap site shows native storage as a feature so I assume that whatever data needs to be accessed w/o a web connection can be stored locally on the devices. Keep in mind that HTML5 is just the markup language used to develop the app. Just because you're developing the app using HTML5 does not mean that your app automatically is depedent on a web connection.